# Send Windows Mouse Events direct to application

Tags: windows, qt, mouseevent

Another new requirement, and apologies if this is vague as I am still at the early stage of trying to figure out how to do it.

I have a interactive whiteboard application written in Qt. It works very well.

The new requirement is to add support for a digitiser pen, which will have 6 buttons, which are to be mapped to functions in the IWB app (e.g. change pen colour).

The pen has a wireless transceiver which plugs into the USB port on the PC.

The first issue I have is the buttons are by default mapped to general mouse type functions, which Windows will "see" first.

I want to, for want of a better word, bypass Windows and have the event go straight to the Qt app.

I am guessing that there might be something within the MS Windows SDK that would help, but does anyone know exactly what?

Comment: This may help you: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractnativeeventfilter.html

Comment: You will need to use platform-specific HID (human interface device) APIs. There are libraries that abstract that out, see e.g. https://github.com/signal11/hidapi